# Handle categorical features with many uniques Tensorflow Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to predict which hotel a given user will book. I have 12 input columns, which are all categorical and are in `INT` format. I am trying to train a Neural Network using `Tensorflow` and `Keras` to predict the feature column `hotel_cluster` which has 6 possible unique values.

The distribution of the data is quite uniform in the `hotel_cluster` label:

[image: Histogram of Distribution]

### Issue 1: One Hot Encoding

I thought that One Hot Encoding was only needed when the categorical features where strings. But then I read that it is used when the categorical features don't mean anything when ordered (Argentina = 1, Chile = 4 does not imply Argenina < Chile).

So I thought about OHEing my columns, but most of the important columns have LOTS of unique values (and can have more that are not seen during training):

```
Col Name                   | Number of Unique Values
---------------------------------------------
site_name :                | 42
user_location_country :    | 218
user_location_region :     | 873
user_location_city :       | 20262
srch_adults_cnt :          | 9
srch_children_cnt :        | 10
srch_rm_cnt :              | 8
srch_destination_id :      | 12713
srch_destination_type_id : | 8
is_booking :               | 2
hotel_continent :          | 7
hotel_country :            | 176
```

1. How do I deal with categorical numerical values in the scenario of a
   DNN?
2. How do I deal with not-seen-during-training categorical values?
3. What methods are there to prepare categorical numerical data
   to use in Tensorflow?
4. If the categorical numerical data makes sense ordered, should I lave
   it 'as-is'?

### Background and Relevant Code

This is the Expedia Problem from Kaggle, but reduced to 6 hotel clusters and 510k samples that was given to me as a prediction task in a class. The task is already past due date, but I want to understand how to make this model just for the sake of it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# DATA
to_predict = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=.2, train_size=.80)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=.2)

# Features and target:
features = ['site_name', 'user_location_country', 'user_location_region',  'user_location_city', 'srch_adults_cnt', 'srch_children_cnt', 'srch_rm_cnt', 'srch_destination_id', 'srch_destination_type_id', 'is_booking', 'hotel_continent', 'hotel_country']

target = 'hotel_cluster'

# Pre Keras processing
X_train = train[features].values
X_test = test[features].values
X_val = val[features].values

label_bin = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = label_bin.fit_transform(train['hotel_cluster'].values)
y_test = label_bin.transform(test['hotel_cluster'].values)
y_val = label_bin.transform(val['hotel_cluster'].values)

X_to_pred = dft[features].values

# Model and fitting
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(12,)),
  layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(len(label_bin.classes_), activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)

H = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=4, batch_size=32)

# Predictions
predictions = model.predict(X_to_pred)
```

predictions looks like this:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

### Expected behaviour

I expect predictions to be a matrix full of numbers that, per row, represent the probability of the label being each of its levels. Currently, it looks like the model doesn't work, and I think it's because the faulty data pre-processing.

I do not know how to make 'train.csv' available to you guys...

Comment: The predictions all assign 1.0 to class 1 and 0 to all other classes. Is there an issue with the values of y_train ? As per your other question all categorical values in features should be one-hot-encoded. As you mention, a country code is not a continuous variable. It is common to reserve one (or more) code value for "not seen in training". i.e. in the case of multiple unknown values this is referred to as the "hashing trick".

Comment: @PedroMarques Thanks!! The histogram that I showed is of y_train, should've clarified that. So, even if I have a column that shows, for instance, arrival order, I should OHE it (or do 'the hashing trick')?